# Not able to run piped shell scripts in jenkins

Tags: shell, ubuntu, jenkins

I am trying to kill all the existing processes before checkout the code and build it, in order to do, I am using the below command.

**sudo ps -ef | grep 'dotnet' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9;**

This is working fine when I run it in the server manually. whereas, using in the jenkins pipeline as Execute Shell script, its not working.

Here is the jenkin's output 
**----------- 
[CICD] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6283168714008394634.sh 
+ ps -ef 
+ grep dotnet 
+ grep -v grep 
+ + awk {print $2}xargs 
 -r kill -9 
Failed build for hudson.tasks.Shell@178f47d3 
**------------ 
Can someone please help?

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the Jenkins pipeline script.

Comment: I am new to Jenkins, using a freestyle project. The issue is with a build step executing shell command. Can you help me more about script you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I just read "pipeline", it was late yesterday.  Try to split up the shell pipeline to see exactly which part of it is failing.